# Dimmable light forgets it's settings when turned off

Tags: electrical, light, dimmer-switch

I've bough these lamps: [lamp 1](https://www.moemax.hu/p/led-mennyezeti-lampa-elian-008227135502), [lamp 2](https://www.moemax.hu/p/premium-living-led-mennyezeti-lampa-bekka-0081810731)

After    turning the light off with the switch, not the remote control, my  lamp   forgets it's color, brightness settings. Plus it turns on with a   random  color/brightness which changes randomly between turn ons. Is   this the  case with all dimmable lamps?

I'm    kinda upset, since i made a whole lot of effort to have 2 switch for    this lamp. The whole point was to have a switch next to the bed, so  you   don't have to climb down from the elevated bed platform.

Comment: This is in some language other than English. What does the instruction manual say? Do you have an instruction manual in English that you can link to here?

Comment: As this is anecdotal, it's not an answer, but I have three different varieties of LED illumination with inline switch for brightness and color temperature. When used with any form of external power management, the setting is lost.

Comment: That's the way most of those work. The makers assume you will only ever use the remote. Or your phone, or Alexa or Siri or Google...

Comment: Nice-looking lamps too. I would replace the driver with one that did what i want. You could probably hack the existing unit in a few ways; use a small battery to keep the MCU on while unpowered, wire all 3 mosfet gate signals to the one switching the LED chain with the color you like, so that all 3 modes do the same color, or just replace it with a dumb driver that turns on and off at the wall; same time every time.

Comment: @dandavis could you explain the first option in more detail?

Comment: They sell 3rd-party LEDs drivers that would replace the one it came with. They can provide new control options or be really simple. If you have a dimmer switch, look for one with "triac dimming". If you want alexa or whatever, they will mention that too. It looks like there's a lot of void space in the lamp to accommodate a large range of drivers. I don't have room here to fully explain how to pick a suitable replacement, that's another question, and it might have been asked already. If not, ask it and i'll tell you more than you want to know.

Comment: @dandavis hey, I asked it in an other thread: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/283306/can-i-just-replace-the-led-controller-of-my-lamp?noredirect=1#comment590189_283306

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a limitation of the circuitry of that "smart" hardware. It *could* have been designed to record its state in something like flash memory and recover that when it powered up again. But that would have cost more, so the manufacturer chose a circuit which doesn't have that feature; it loses its memory when it loses power.

You could try to find fancier hardware which has the additional non-volatile state storage. Emphasis on try.

Or you could not use the wall switch. Maybe tape a remote to your wall. It'll still lose memory if you have a power outage. You could even install a wall-mounted smart switch and use it just as a transmitter, ignoring it's output and wiring the circuit as permanently on, then have your smart home logic respond to the switch by sending a signal to the lamp... though if you were going to go in that direction I'd have installed the smart switch normally and plugged in dumb lamps.

Comment: The cost to storing settings like this in non-volatile memory is non-trivial. Right off the bat you'll now need some micro-OS to handle writing and reading of data, and then you'll need both code and a controller to use those data and set the device to whatever the data wrote.

Comment: Most of those components have to be in the smart device anyway -- but every feature added means possibly having to upgrade to a slightly more powerful microcontroller, or add external components. Which may only be a fraction of a cent per, in bulk quantities, but when you're making millions of the widget that adds up. (I really hate that edits after a few minutes require delete-and-repost, but SE thinks that's necessary. Grumble.)

Comment: anything smart (using wifi or bt) will already have flash memory onboard to store wifi SSID and other config. It's hard to get micros w/o flash or at least eeprom these days...

Comment: @dandavis: But these aren't "smart". And even smart IoT devices get devices sized for that particular product, rather than overkilling it as hobbyists generally do because for a one-off the component price is so much smaller than design and build costs.

Comment: Can I just replace the LED driver? Can you recommend something? This is the current one: https://img.istreetview.com/?id=hsF0gw05&url=3cRltBdhUaYc2lJ275Ez4NhqjMmC+vaqAQ4m3zXbsrDDGm94YNcv67oTZnzqzskrAM6BnSdWhIaxHknimPYxlJjEjnT+5ml1vytmWw==

Comment: Maybe, if you can find one with the right specs that you know has the right behavior. No, I can't recommend one.