# Need helping finding light switch for chandeliers

Tags: lighting

I recently bought a chandelier where every time you turn it on and off the light will cycle through one of three modes from cool to warm. Is there a light switch out there that let's me select which mode I want to turn on? The remote and switch that came with the chandelier doesn't have that feature and it seems the only way to switch between these modes is to turn the chandelier on and off. That means each time I want the chandelier to have white light, I need to turn it off and on 3 times.

Comment: Unless that fixture has a smart-home interface, I'm afraid the answer is probably no. Specific make and model?

Comment: It sounds like a bad design defect.  A simple three way switch in the light to control colours with the wall switch as just on/off should not be that hard to design in.  I would think about returning it as defective(stupid design).

Comment: Make/model number?

Comment: Awfully similar to https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/282733/dimmable-light-forgets-its-settings-when-turned-off

Comment: I would hard-wire the mains switch on, then use a momentary switch (like a garbage disposal switch) to operate an IR blaster than cloned the included remote's on/off codes. Or replace the LED driver with one that behaved how you want. It's WAY easier to mod/swap the electronics than to produce a safe and nice-looking light fixture. The nice thing about LED fixtures is that you have 1000s of options on how to power and control them. The bad side? You have 1000s of options to sort through.

Answer (score 3):

The cycling is done through internal electronics that are designed with the chandelier.

A switch will only open or close the circuit. A dimmer will probably make the unit inoperable.

Your best bet is returning the chandelier and purchasing something that you like.