# Can I just replace the LED controller of my lamp?

Tags: led, lamp, remote-control

I've bough [this lamp](https://www.moemax.hu/p/led-mennyezeti-lampa-elian-008227135502).

After turning the light off with the switch, not the remote control, my lamp forgets it's color, brightness settings. Plus it turns on with a random color/brightness which changes randomly between turn ons.

Can I just replace the LED control of this lamp? If so, could you recommend something to buy? Or the guidelines on how to buy a proper one?

This is the [current driver](https://img.istreetview.com/?id=hsF0gw05&url=3cRltBdhUaYc2lJ275Ez4NhqjMmC%20vaqAQ4m3zXbsrDDGm94YNcv67oTZnzqzskrAM6BnSdWhIaxHknimPYxlJjEjnT%205ml1vytmWw==).

Comment: I would suspect that in general, the answer is "no". You're not likely to be able to replace the LED driver of a smart device except, maybe, with a like-for-like replacement from the original manufacturer.. There are some that can be reprogrammed with a variety of different controller software, but you're going to have to do a lot of research to figure out if yours is flashable and, therefore, reprogrammable.

Comment: That driver is actually pretty unique, so a direct replacement will be difficult, but with some expectation adjustments there's   options available. Do you want the dimming to happen from a wall switch instead of the remote? Are you ok not using the remote? Are you ok with having just one color work? If yes to all, something like the meanwell PCD-60-1050B is electrically compatible with the LEDs in the lamp.

Comment: @dandavis no that won't work for me unfortunately, but much thanks anyways

Comment: @dandavis so, If I buy a TRIAC dimmer and replace the original driver with this one, I will be able to dim it, but with the switch right? Is that correct?

Comment: Yeah, a new "dumb" driver that responds to triac would let you dim it from the switch. I like the ones with a push on/push off rotary knob because they let you turn it on/off w/o resetting the dim level. Some slide dimmers also have a small rocker switch underneath which accomplishes the same; on or off without dimming. Lastly, a smart switch dimmer can do all that an allow access from an app or alexa or other controls if you have a smart home setup.

Comment: @dandavis Why wouldn't I be able to change the color with the dimmer? What would be the color of the lamp then? Can I change it in any way?

Comment: each color is basically a different light. Normally, one dimmer can control one light. The one that came with it is a special one-off design that does two different dimming "channels", changing the proportion of each color strip to tune the output color temp.

Comment: @dandavisI see. So what will  be the color of it than? I also really appreciate your answers though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not designed to ever have the power to it switched off, same as most smart devices these days.

You need to remove the switch, or replace with a remote switch designed to talk to the lamp, like the remote does… or fasten the remote on the wall in place of the switch.